# Jenkins Slave Agent - Ubuntu: port out range:-1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm trying to get Jenkins slave agent running in VM. I have Windows and Ubuntu VMs, Windows one running fine. However getting an error when Slave Agent is starting on Ubuntu:

Start command:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl
https://SERVER/ci/computer/MACHINE/slave-agent.jnlp -secret XXX
```

Error:

```
Skipping HTTPS certificate checks altogether. Note that this is not secure at all.
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:58 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: MACHINE
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:58 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:58 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating SERVER among [https://SERVER/ci/]
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:59 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting SERVER accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, JNLP-connect, Ping, JNLP2-connect]
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: SERVER
  Agent port:    51967
  Identity:      XXX
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to SERVER:51967
Sep 22, 2017 12:57:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: port out of range:-1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.getResolvedHttpProxyAddress(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:359)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:193)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:500)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:364)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:287)
```

the error:

**SEVERE: port out of range:-1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1**

any ideas?

Comment: SOLVED .. caused by proxy settings

Answer (score 1):

Same for me, it was caused by proxy settings, I solved that adding NO_PROXY environment variable with appropriate hostname